# Return Argv[0] via method in a CommandLine Handling Class | C++

Tags: c++, class, argv

I know that (at least in C++ and I assume anytime it's used) argv[0] refers to the file path as the program is usually the first argument listed there.  For the project I'm working on for class, I've made a class that handles the command line (as far as the constraints of the project, we're making a project that can read in text files and count uniqueness of words)

**SO I'll stop blabbing and get to the question - in my command line class I would like a method to "return argv[0];" but saying that implicitly in a method didn't work.** Here's my code for the headerfile, and the class:

CmdLine.h

```
#pragma once

#include<string>
#include<algorithm>

class CmdLine
{
public:
    CmdLine( int argc, char* argv[] );
    ~CmdLine();

    std::string getFile ( int index );
    int getNumFiles ( void );

    std::string getFlag ( int index );
    int getNumFlags( void );
    bool isFlag ( char c );

    std::string getCommandPath ( );

private:
    int myArgc;
    char** myArgv;

    int myNumFiles;
    std::string myFileNames[ 100 ];

     int myNumFlags;
    std::string myFlags[ 100 ];

private:
    CmdLine( const CmdLine& other );
    CmdLine& operator=( const CmdLine& rhs );
};
```

CmdLine.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "CmdLine.h"

using namespace std;

CmdLine::CmdLine(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    myArgc = argc;
    myArgv = argv;
    myNumFiles = 0;
    myNumFlags = 0;

    for ( int i = 1; i < argc ; i++ )
    {
        std::string arg = argv[i];
        if ( arg[0] == '/' )
        {
            myFlags[ myNumFlags++ ] = argv[i];
        }
        else
        {
            myFileNames[ myNumFiles++ ] = argv[i];
        }
    }
}

CmdLine::~CmdLine()
{}

int CmdLine::getNumFiles ( void )
{  
    return myNumFiles;
}

string CmdLine::getFile ( int index )
{
    //Check to see if index < number of files
     return myFileNames[ index ];
}

int CmdLine::getNumFlags ( void )
{
    return myNumFlags;
}

string CmdLine::getFlag( int index )
{
    return myFlags[ index ];
}

//string CmdLine::getCommandPath ( )
//{
//  return 
//}
```

Comment: Those parameters (argc and argv) are *only* passed to the main function by default. Where do you create an instance of the CmdLine class?

Comment: It gets created in the main function of my program.  I just want to be able to return a string representing the file path without having to like, make a function for it in main. My teacher specifically doesn't want it cluttered. xD

Comment: `myArgv[0]` should work based on your code.

Comment: Oh hey that totally did the trick! Thanks @RetiredNinja!!